# Varnish sending headers, but not caching content?

Tags: php, apache, caching, varnish, varnish-vcl

I've been trying to figure out the issue for hours. I'm using a simple PHP script echoing the current time() to check if Varnish is working correctly (the time should stop updating on refresh). However, when I request the test script the time continually updates, BUT the headers are saying everything is ok:

```
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
    X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.9
    Vary: Accept-Encoding
    Content-Type: text/html
    Date: Sat, 08 Feb 2014 18:11:04 GMT
    X-Varnish: 24284714 24284713
    Age: 4
    Via: 1.1 varnish
    Connection: keep-alive
```

Varnish age, above is 4 because I just restarted the service. The strange thing is, the time on the php test page changes (so the copy isn't being served from varnish cache)... yet the varnish headers continue to 'think' the original copy is being served as the age increments and the page still updates the time when refreshed.

Could it be possible it's working, but can't access it's own cached pages somehow?

Could there be something simple I'm missing? Varnish was working 100% OK a few weeks ago and I've just looked back into it to get a server online after development and can't wrap my head around why it has stopped functioning.

Love to hear some ideas to get this solved ASAP.

Comment: Do you have access to the vcl and are you sure it's configured correctly to cache the page you are requesting. Also in those headers I can't see any cache-control header. This page might help with setting headers varnish requires and debugging further. https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/increasing_your_hitrate.html

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. I cleared my cache and oddly it served an old version of the page - leading me to believe it was a cookie issue. So I disabled all cookies via the config file and all is working. Thanks for the suggestions buddy.